# QT and native OpenGL support in MS Windows

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, visual-studio-2013, qt5.3

I'm trying to import the [cube](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-example.html) example in MS visual studio 2013 via the QT add-in.

Unfortunately, when trying to open the `.pro` file I get the following error:

> `Project ERROR: This example requires Qt to be configured with -opengl desktop`

Doing a little research in the web I realized that by default QT OpenGL support is build on [ANGLE-library](https://code.google.com/p/angleproject/) which as I realized is an OpenGL to DirectX9.0 kind of translator.

Thus, I have two options ([link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22821/#107114)):

1. Install ANGLE.
2. Recompile QTv5.3 with option `-opengl desktop`.

The problem is that I installed QTv5.3 via [QT online installer for windows](http://qt-project.org/downloads).

### Q:

Considering the above, how am I supposed to recompile QTv5.3 with native OpenGL support (i.e.,  with `-opengl desktop` option) when I've installed QTv5.3 via the windows online installer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you can compile it yourself with any flags you wish, there is a simpler option.
Qt online installer provides several distributions: different versions of Qt, for different targets, with or without OpenGL support.

### Easiest way to install Qt 5.3.2 MSVC 2013 OpenGL:

- run `<QT_FOLDER>\MaintenanceTool.exe` (or online installer if you have never installed Qt yet)
- choose `Package manager`, press `Next`
- Under `Qt`->`5.3` check `msvc2013 32-bit OpenGL` (along with any other version you need)
- Press `Next`...

It will be installed in `<QT_FOLDER>\msvc2013_opengl`

Then you probably will need to pointVisual Studio AddIn to correct Qt folder (it can carry multiple versions).

### Easiest way to make Qt and MSVC friends

You can easily generate Visual Studio `.vcxproj` file from Qt' project `.pro` file by running `qmake`. No any addons required.

To do this:

- open `VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt` (or set up path with `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86`)
- add desired Qt version to path:

  ```
  set PATH=%PATH%;<QT_FOLDER>\msvc2013_opengl\bin
  ```
- go to Qt project folder and generate MSVC project:

  ```
  cd <pro_folder>
  qmake -tp vc
  ```
- You will find in the same folder a `.vcxproj` file with all Qt's bells and whistles (moc'ing, uic'ing, rcc'ing etc.) set up like build events
- Repeat this operation whenever you change `.pro` file. Reload `.vcxproj` each time (no need to close Visual Studio; it will ask you to reload when it detects changes). Consider `.vcxproj` as temporary, generated file and don't change it manually. Tweak all the stuff in `.pro`.

Hint: write `.bat` file to do all this stuff automatically.

HTH

Comment: Thanks, for later versions (5.15.2) you can find it in the package manager under Qt > Developer and Designer Tools > ...OpenGL Runtime... for x

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to download and build either the [32-bit version](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.2/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_opengl-5.3.2.exe) or the [64-bit version](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.2/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64_opengl-5.3.2.exe).

I built from scratch, but for ANGLE, not OpenGL.

[This page](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-5-on-Windows-ANGLE-and-OpenGL) should be read before you decide on going either direction.