# Qt Quick 2 and OpenGL 4.1

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5, qtquick2

I want to use Qt Quick 2.x for my program but I can't make it work with OpenGL > 2.0

I have `main.qml`:

```
/* imports */
Window {
    ...
    Scene {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In `Scene` I'm using OpenGL > 2.0 so my shaders aren't working.

I've tried to add this line `qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine.rootObjects().first())->setFormat(format_3_3);` in main.cpp but that didn't help.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSurfaceFormat format_3_3;
    format_3_3.setMajorVersion(3);
    format_3_3.setMinorVersion(3);
    format_3_3.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CompatibilityProfile);

    qmlRegisterType<Scene>("SceneGL", 1, 0, "Scene");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(engine.rootObjects().first())->setFormat(format_3_3);

    return app.exec();
}
```

My `Scene` class:

```
class Scene : public QQuickItem
{
    ...
}
```

I found a solution [here (47 minute)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYa5DLV6ADQ) but without source code I can't see full picture to use the same technique.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: windows? then you need to configure your QT install to use openGL otherwise it just has opengl ES 2.0 see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813229/qt-and-native-opengl-support-in-ms-windows

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X 10.10

Comment: Mac does not implement Compatibility profiles. You need to request a Core profile if you want GL >= 3.x. Moreover, the way you set the format is totally hackish. Much better to subclass QQuickWindow and set the format in the constructor of your subclass.