# windows 7, qt 5.7, Intel (HD) Graphics Family, OpenGL V 3.1

Tags: c++, opengl, windows-7, qt5.7

In trying to run a Qt app on a Windows 7 laptop it says the following (and keeps repeating the):

```
shader compilation failed: 
"Failed to create D3D shaders.\n"
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
Failed to create D3D shaders.

QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( matrix ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( color ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( textureScale ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation( dpr ): shader program is not linked
QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
```

The output above is from the 'Application Output' window in QtCreator.

I am using windows 7, Intel (HD) Graphics Family: Driver version 8.15.10.2559, OpenGL version 3.1

The OpenGL version is from OpenGL Extensions Viewer
The Driver version was retrieved from Screen Resolution->Advanced Settings->Properties->Driver

Edit 1:
The app runs on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04). I moved it without any modifications to my Windows 7 laptop. I'm using Qt 5.7 on both laptops (Linux & Windows). It built on Windows 7 without any complaints. It built and ran on Linux without any complaints. I thought I might have an OpenGL version issue, but OpenGL Viewer says that my system has OpenGL 3.1.

Comment: Please provide the code that's causing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error log

> ```
> shader compilation failed: 
> "Failed to create D3D shaders.\n"
> QOpenGLShader::link: Failed to create D3D shaders.
> ```

strongly suggests that the Qt build you're using is using the ANGLE OpenGL (on top of Direct3D) emulation layer. You can find Qt in two build variants and ANGLE is the more widely deployed one in Windows, because the default drivers installed in Windows lack modern OpenGL support… which makes applications requiring modern OpenGL features, like Qt5 fail. Hence there's a Qt5 build variant that contains this emulation layer.

In your case you probably want to install (or probably already did so) the native OpenGL driver for your GPU (obtainable directly from the vendor website) *and* use a Qt build configured to use the native OpenGL implementation around (Qt built with `-opengl desktop` configuration). See also [QT and native OpenGL support in MS Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813229/qt-and-native-opengl-support-in-ms-windows)

Comment: Thanks datenwolf, that nailed it.