# How to run opengl example project on Qt 5.9 and Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, qt, opengl

I installed Qt 5.9 online and then I run an opengl example project named "boxes". It showed error when I built.

> :-1: error: This example requires Qt to be configured with -opengl
>   desktop

I tried to fixed it using the answers to the question [QT and native OpenGL support in MS Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26813229/4284627), but failed.
The site said that "different versions of Qt, for different targets, with or without OpenGL support". I'm using Qt 5.9 and I can't find any options `msvc201x xx-bit OpenGL`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QT and native OpenGL support in MS Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813229/qt-and-native-opengl-support-in-ms-windows)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Qt SDK has rich set of examples related to OpenGL usage.

Comment: And still this is a problem.... If you need to recompile it, come on... 2020... _"'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"_  something with a path?  garbage it is...

Answer (score 0):

> This example requires Qt to be configured with -opengl desktop

The question is about configuring Qt and the author likely has Qt which is configured different than the example project requires.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html

```
configure.bat -opengl desktop
```

Mind that Qt also needs to be built with this option. And you don't necessarily need to build Qt but can get via Qt Maintenance tool etc.

Answer (score 0):

As of Qt 5.5 the pre-built packages are built with the opengl dynamic option as documented [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html#dynamically-loading-graphics-drivers):

> **Note:** As of Qt 5.5 this [`-opengl dynamic`] is the configuration used by the official,
>   pre-built binary packages of Qt.

Therefore the only option is to build it from source as described by AlexanderVX.